# What is the connection of autorelease pool to garbage collection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, garbage-collection, autorelease

i have read this from apple docs..

In a garbage collected environment, release is a no-op (a do-nothing instruction). NSAutoreleasePool therefore provides a drain method that in a reference-counted environment behaves the same as calling release, but which in a garbage collected environment triggers garbage collection (if the memory allocated since the last collection is greater than the current threshold). Typically, therefore, you should use drain rather than release to dispose of an autorelease pool.

*but not getting the meaning of*

1) **"if the memory allocated since the last collection is greater than the current threshold."**

*and*

2) **ios is not supporting garbage collector then what is the use of drain with garbage collector ?**

Comment: Dude can i have that Link please i want to read it myself.

Comment: Yes , Addicted you can find it https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW4

Answer (score 2):

1) It probably means that the GC remembers the amount of allocated memory, and the next time `drain` is called the amount of allocated memory is compared with the last amount. Only if the change is significant enough garbage collection takes place.

Let me explain it in a different way: garbage collection can be expensive, so you need to decide when to collect. In order to avoid unnecessary work, the GC might remember the amount of memory after a collection run (for example, 25MB are used). Now the next time the GC considers collecting, it first decides whether it's worth doing all the work. For example, if the amount of memory used is now 25.5MB it's probably not worth doing anything. But if now 50MB are in use the collecting is useful.

2) This stuff originated on the Mac, where GC is available. To enable sharing of code between iOS and Mac OS X, these seemingly unnecessary methods still stick around on iOS to remain as compatible with Mac OS X as possible. I even suspect it's due to the fact that iOS is actually a "fork" of Mac OS X and thus inherited this stuff.

Comment: and for 2) drain is useful only when sharing of code between ios and mac is required ?

Comment: ane for 1) when i calling drain, it is going to compare memory with last amout or it is going to remove those memory ?

Comment: @PJR: `drain` is also the only option for destroying an autorelease pool with ARC (though you'll probably be using the `@autoreleasepool` directive nowadays).

Comment: @PJR: No, it's not comparing memory. What the GC is doing, I don't know. But the docs suggest that it remembered the *amount of memory used*, and compares that number with the *current amount of memory used*. Only if the difference is big enough the GC starts cleaning up "abandoned" objects.